# Azure SMS message is not received on phone after a successful response

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-communication-services

I'm using the latest Azure Communication SMS package, and basically directly copy/pasted the sample code to try sending a text to my cell. I got a successful 202 code back and can see the event successfully in the event grid I set up. But my phone never got the text, if it helps T-Mobile is my cell provider and I reside in the US with a US cell number.

Here is my code sample and response with sensitive information redacted

```
public sendSms = async (message: string, numbers: string[]) => {
    if (this.checkIfReachLimit()) {
        return;
    }
    const endpoint = `https://<resource name>.communication.azure.com`;
    const credential = new AzureKeyCredential("<cred>");
    const client = new SmsClient(endpoint, credential);
    try {
        const sendResults = await client.send(
            {
                from: "My Azure Toll Free #", // Your E.164 formatted phone number used to send SMS
                to: numbers, // The list of E.164 formatted phone numbers to which message is being sent
                message, // The message being sent
            },
            {
                enableDeliveryReport: true,
                tag: "workoutBuilder",
            },
        );
        this.updateMonthlyCount(sendResults.length);
        for (const sendResult of sendResults) {
            if (sendResult.successful) {
                console.log("Success: ", sendResult);
            } else {
                console.error("Something went wrong when trying to send this message: ", sendResult);
            }
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        // no op
    }
};
```

Response:

```
{
  to: 'my cell',
  messageId: 'message id',
  httpStatusCode: 202,
  repeatabilityResult: 'accepted',
  successful: true
}
```

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue. Does anyone have a resolution?